# R - Find all possible combinations splitted word

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a function which extracts all meaningful words from a string. After this, I would like to create all possible sentences from these words.

For example:

```
MyString <- "temelproblem"
```

After splitting with my function I get a dataframe like this;

```
Data <- data.frame(
myword = c("te","tem","teme","temel","em","eme","emel","me","mel","el","pr","problem","em"),
start = c(1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  6,  6, 11),
finish = c(2,  3,  4,  5,  3,  4,  5,  4,  5,  5,  7, 12, 12)
)

> Data
    myword start finish
1       te     1      2
2      tem     1      3
3     teme     1      4
4    temel     1      5
5       em     2      3
6      eme     2      4
7     emel     2      5
8       me     3      4
9      mel     3      5
10      el     4      5
11      pr     6      7
12 problem     6     12
13      em    11     12
```

I need all possible combinations and the rule is; next word should start after previous word finish. From this sample I sould get;

```
"tem" "el" "problem"
"temel" "problem"
```

I will be grateful for guiding ideas...

Comment: how many sub-words ? your first example you have three sub-word, and in your second examples you have two. Can you clarify that in your question ?

Comment: Number of sub-words are not important. Only rule is start-finish continuity. First combination is: tem(1:3)-el(4:5)-problem(6:12) and the second is: temel(1:5)-problem(6:12).